# Python:: How to interpret the output of Arch's ADF function's regression?

Tags: regression, python, spearman-rho, augmented-dickey-fuller, kendall-tau

```
I have the following output from the regression function of Python's ARCH library. What do all the headers mean in the second table. coeff, std.error,t, P >|t| and [0.025 0.975]. The ADF test was run with a lag of 3 and no trend.

The bigger question I have is, and sorry if I come across as totally silly, are coeff & t equivalent to 
Rho(Spearman Correlation coefficient) & Tau(Kendall-Tau) respectively?


                                 OLS Regression Results                                
=======================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared (uncentered):                   0.140
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared (uncentered):              0.115
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                              5.550
Date:                Mon, 13 Apr 2020   Prob (F-statistic):                    0.000361
Time:                        19:19:51   Log-Likelihood:                         -520.63
No. Observations:                 140   AIC:                                      1049.
Df Residuals:                     136   BIC:                                      1061.
Df Model:                           4                                                  
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                                  
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level.L1      -0.1299      0.056     -2.332      0.021      -0.240      -0.020
Diff.L1       -0.1947      0.092     -2.124      0.035      -0.376      -0.013
Diff.L2       -0.1949      0.089     -2.193      0.030      -0.371      -0.019
Diff.L3       -0.0647      0.086     -0.752      0.453      -0.235       0.105
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      137.102   Durbin-Watson:                   2.024
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):             2596.759
Skew:                           3.427   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Kurtosis:                      22.955   Cond. No.                         2.44
==============================================================================

ADF results
=====================================
Test Statistic                 -2.332
P-value                         0.019
Lags                                3
-------------------------------------

Trend: No Trend
Critical Values: -2.58 (1%), -1.94 (5%), -1.62 (10%)
Null Hypothesis: The process contains a unit root.
Alternative Hypothesis: The process is weakly stationary.
```